# note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'const int *'

Tags: c++, c

При компиляции программы, выводит следующее `note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'const int *'`, при этом всё компилируется и программа отлично работает. Однако, мне всё же интересно, чего же здесь не понравилось компилятору. Несколько раз проверял, но так и не понял, откуда взялся указатель на целое число.
Вот код:

```
int some_function(const char* string);

int main(const int argc, const int* argv[])
{
    int some_int = some_function(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}

int some_function(const char* string)
{
    int some_int;
    ...
    return some_int;
}
```

Comment: думаю, нужно привести больше кода. может там какие то define есть или перегрузки.

Comment: надо не больше кода, а [mcve]

Comment: Я изменил пример, есть перегрузка, define'ов нету, программа сразу же вызывает функцию.

Comment: Прежде чем сто-то постить, убедитесь, что в **приведенном** коде проблема воспроизводится, а лучше сразу добавляйте ссылку на онлайн компилятор с подтверждением наличия заявленной проблемы.

Comment: Всё, прошу прощения, моя вина, ошибка была в том, что вместо `char* argv[]`, я написал `int* argv[]`.

Comment: тогда удаляйте вопрос...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У параметров `main` должны быть типы `int` и `char*[]`, а не `const int*`, `const char*`, `const char*[]` и так далее. Либо без параметров

Comment: Вопрос уже решён, но спасибо)

Comment: @СупрематическийКрестьянин примите ответ тогда

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в том, что, из-за невнимательности, вместо `char* argv[]` в объявления функции `main`, я написал `int* argv[]`.